# Integrate Google account login into a iOS app

Tags: ios, mobile, authentication, integration

I want to login in my iOS App with a Google account. Instead of having a database with users and having to register all the users, I simply login with my existing Google account.

Anyone knows a way of doing this, or a tutorial?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

[Google Accounts Authentication and Authorization for Mobile Apps](https://developers.google.com/accounts/docs/MobileApps) has fairly detailed instructions for authenticating Google account users and includes iOS-specific steps.

Comment: Yea well if that worked ok we wouldn't need SO, wouldn't we? So some practical examples of actually working code would be nice ;).